# Brackets at the start of input in matlab ?? [ x , y ] = 

Tags: matlab, input

I would like to know what is the use of having inputs in brackets like this :

`[fx, fxx] = differentiate(...)`
why is `fx` and `fxx` in square brackets ?

Another example includes this `[y,t,ysd] = step(m)`

Please explain !

Thanks

Comment: This is quite basic Matlab syntax.  Supplement your questions to SO with some reading of the (generally very good) documentation written by the Mathworks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matlab allows multiple return values. fx and fxx will each be assigned a return value of the function.

Comment: So fx and fxx will hold the outputs of that function right ?? What if there was one result ?